# creating new array in jQuery with specified length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I create a blank array of length 4 in jQuery. I want to create the array first and later want to punch values in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array` Constructor, [`new Array(arrayLength)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax)

```
var array = new Array(4);
```

Note: This array is not essentially *blank*, it contains `undefined` but it's length is `4`.

If **feasible**,

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Comment: and also with var array = ["1","2"] with default values.

console.log(array.length)

Comment: @Akki619 I've updated answer, but it is not always possible, when you have large number of elements and you want to create array dynamically, instead of loop, `Array` constructor is better choice.